Axionic Electroweak Baryogenesis
I am trying to read an article "Axionic Electroweak Baryogenesis", where first-order electroweak phase transition is generated by an axionic-Higgs coupling (given in the following potential).
$$V(\theta,H)=-\Lambda^4 \cos \theta+ [\mu^2-M^2\cos(\theta+\alpha)] |H|^2 + \lambda |H|^4$$
where $H$ is the usual Higgs doublet, and $\theta=\phi/f$ ($\phi$ is the axion field with the discrete symmetry $\phi\rightarrow \phi + 2\pi f$)
I would like to see if the phase transition is one-step or multistep.
Further, how do I check at which scale the axion is getting its vev? Is the potential given enough for me to know about my questions?
